# i don't understand @unordered{@array} in perl

Tags: perl

I'm inexperienced programmer in Perl. I'm already reading the book Beginning Perl Curtis “Ovid” Poe and have problem with this code.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use diagnostics;
my @array = ( 3, 4, 1, 4, 7, 7, 4, 1, 3, 8 );
my %unordered;
@unordered{@array} = undef;
foreach my $key (keys %unordered) {
print “Unordered: $key\n”;
}
```

@unordered{@array} = undef;

what does this code mean ?
Could anyone explain me ?

Answer (score 4):

```
@unordered{@array} = undef
```

This is called a `hash slice` . You can read more [about it here](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html#Slices) or [here](http://www.sysarch.com/Perl/hash_slice.txt) or [here](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=438284). In other words, it acts on multiple keys of the hash(the keys are described by `@array`, and in this particular case, it assigns the value `undef` to each of those keys).

Answer (score 1):

I assume it is to show you some things about the keys of hashes.
You have the `@array` and then create entries in your hash `%unordered` with the values from your array as keys and no values. This happens in this line:

@unordered{@array} = undef;

You then iterate through all the keys of that hash and print them. So you can see what keys there are and in what order they are in the hash.
You will probably notice how every key exists only once despite several values being more than once in the array. This is because keys of hashes always are unique.
Also you could see how the keys are in no particular order as the keys of a hash may be ordered in any way the implementation likes.

Comment: Duplicate entries in the array (1,3,4,7) are only printed once because they only exist in the hash once. So the code filters duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I understand all what you're explaining to me. Tkank you for your time.

But why, first of all we initiation an array with numbers, then create a hash (blank hash), then we create entries in hash %unordered with the values from array as keys and no values.

By in loop for, we use an "%" (%unordered). We change array "@array" to hash "%unordered", and then we use in loop for again %unordered.

It looks a bit strange